# How to get specific value from one table, groups same ID and same value?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Assuming to have this table sample, and to have the same groups of IDs and ValuesA, i want to get records specific ValueB.
Let me show it:

DB used: Postgres

This is my sample table and assuming to split (without really split my table in code) in 3 groups I want to get the following cases below:

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| ID  | ValueA | ValueB  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 123 |     1  |   PIP   |
| 123 |     1  |   POP   |
| 123 |     1  |   PIP   |
| 456 |     2  |   COP-1 |
| 456 |     2  |   COP-2 |
| 456 |     2  |   COP-2 |
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DOP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

CASE 1:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| ID  | ValueA | ValueB |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 123 |     1  |   PIP  |
| 123 |     1  |   POP  |
| 123 |     1  |   PIP  |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

From this table i'd like to get only this value:

`123 |     1  |   POP`

CASE 2

```
+-----+--------+----------+
| ID  | ValueA | ValueB   |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 456 |     2  |   COP-1  |
| 456 |     2  |   COP-2  |
| 456 |     2  |   COP-2  |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

From this table i'd like to get only this value:

`456 |     2  |   COP-1`

CASE 3

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| ID  | ValueA | ValueB  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DOP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
| 789 |     5  |   DIP   |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

From this table i'd like to get the record which appears several times, but must not be the first or the last record

`789 |     5  |   DIP`

I'd like to get 3 queries, for each of those results.

Please help me.

I tried in several ways but i still not founded e method or right statement.

Is there here one method to get this with PostgreSQL code, or also script-code like Python/Bash idk?

Comment: Show the several ways you have tried it.

Comment: First method:
`WITH added_row_number AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY result DESC) AS row_number
  FROM exam_results
)
SELECT
  *
FROM added_row_number
WHERE row_number = 1;`

Second method:
`with added_row_number as (
select *,
row_number() over(partition by "IdClient" order by "Client") as row_number
from public.v_client_con_utilizzatori_con_data_più_recente 
)
select * from added_row_number
--where row_number = 1
where "Client" in (
 select "Client"  
 from added_row_number 
 group by "UltimaData" 
)`

Comment: Put it in the question. Not in the comment. So its formatted and other can see it better too.

Answer (score -1):

First method:

```
WITH added_row_number AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ValueA ORDER BY Id DESC) AS row_number
  FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM added_row_number
WHERE row_number = 1 and ValueB ilike 'POP'
```

Second method:

```
with added_row_number as (
select *,
row_number() over(partition by "Id" order by "Id") as row_number
from table 
)
select * from added_row_number
where "Id" in (
    select "Id"  
    from added_row_number 
    group by "ValueA"   
)
```

Comment: details should be added in the question, it is not an answer

Comment: Right @AzatIbrakov, I'm sorry, this is my first post here, i still have to get well knowledge about operation